# SQL: Check if at least one element of an array is in subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I have a table like this:

```
id | name | artists
-------------------
1  | XYZ  | {Some Dude, Whatever}
2  | ABC  | {Blah Blah Blah, Whatever}
3  | EFG  | {Running, Out, Of, Made, Up, Names}
```

I have a subquery that returns one column called `name` with a bunch of artist's names. I need a way to check if at least one of the elements of `artists` (for each of the rows) is contained in the results of that subquery. That is, if the subquery returns this:

```
name
----
Some Dude
Whatever
Blah Blah Blah
```

then, I want to select only the rows with id 1 and 2 in my example, because none of the artists in id 3 are returned by the subquery.

I do know I can do `single_element = ANY(subquery)` but that only tests a single element. I've tried doing:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ANY(artists) = ANY(subquery)
```

but that fails immediately with "ERROR: syntax error at or near 'any'".

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show us the query you have that is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `&&` operator to test for set-element overlap. Its documented in the [postgresql documentation section on array functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html)

```
WITH artists (name) AS (
VALUES 
    ('Blah Blah Blah'::text), 
    ('Whatever'), 
    ('Some Dude')
),
my_table (id, name, artists) AS (
VALUES 
    (1,'XYZ',ARRAY['Some Dude'::TEXT, 'Whatever'::TEXT]),
    (2,'ABC',ARRAY['Blah Blah Blah', 'Whatever']),
    (3,'EFG',ARRAY['Running', 'Out', 'Of', 'Made', 'Up', 'Names'])
)
SELECT * 
FROM my_table 
WHERE artists && (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(name) FROM artists)
```

Also, from my example above you can see how to convert a subquery into an array to be able to use the `overlaps` operator